# If $ax^2 +bxy+cy^2+5x-2y+3$ divided by $x-y+1$ has remainder $0$, determine $a$, $b$, and $c$.

Tags: polynomials

> If $ax^2 +bxy+cy^2+5x-2y+3$ divided by $x-y+1$ has remainder $0$, determine $a$, $b$, and $c$.

I do not know how to approach this problem and would appreciate advice how to proceed.

Comment: So what did you try to do?

Comment: Like in one variable, substitute suitable values of $z$ and $y$.

Comment: Given constants $f,g,h,$ what is $$  (fx + gy + h))(x-y+1)? $$

Comment: Can x=y or is that obviously disallowed?

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no remainder the original equation will be the product of $x-y+1$ with another unknown equation. In order to create the $x^2$, $y^2$, and $xy$ terms we expect the form to be $dx+ey+f$.

$$ax^2+bxy+cy^2+5x−2y+3  = (x−y+1)(dx+ey+f)$$
$$ax^2+bxy+cy^2+5x−2y+3  = dx^2+(e-d)xy-ey^2+(d+f)x+(e-f)y+f$$

working right to left

$$f=3$$

$$e-f=-2, e=1$$

$$d+f=5, d=2$$

$$c=-e, c=-1$$

$$b=e-d, b=-1$$

$$a=d, a=2$$

Answer (score 0):

In $ax^2+bxy+cy^2+5x−2y+3  = (x−y+1)(dx+ey+f)$, put $x=0, y=1$ to get $c+1 = 0$ and hence $c=-1$. Put $y=0, x=-1$ to get $a-2=0$ and hence $a=2$. Putting $x=1, y = 2$, we get $a+2b+4c+5-4+3 = 0$ and hence $b=-1$.